# In vim's visual mode (type "v"), how do I select multiple lines?

Tags: linux, unix, vim, editing

What are the shortcuts that I need to know, to make it snap snap?

Right now, all I do it the up/down arrow...it's noobish.

Comment: Start by using k and j to go up and down.

Comment: Why should I use j/k to go up down?

Comment: Because then you can keep your fingers on the home row.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same as normal mode; use `<n>G` to go to a specific line.

Also, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>.

Comment: The second <key>j</key> should be a <key>k</key>

Comment: Boys, if you have a disagreement, discuss it in chat, not here. *Comments deleted*

Answer (score 3):

`{` and `}` are very handy motions, they go respectively to the beginning or end of a paragraph.

Use `v` then `}` and you've selected all the paragraph until the end in two key strokes.

Alternatively you can use **text-objects**.

Basically,
`vip` selects the current paragraph,
`vis` selects the current sentence,
etc

See `:help text-objects` for more

Answer (score 2):

Same as normal mode; use `<n>` plus one movement operator:

- <kbd>G</kbd> to go to line `n`
- <kbd>j</kbd> to go down `n` lines
- <kbd>k</kbd> to go up `n` lines
- <kbd>w</kbd> to go right `n` words

etc. see `:help motion` and get familiar with that.